# CoreStorage: what does LVG status 'offline' and PV status 'checking' mean and how can it be fixed?

Tags: disk-utility, filevault, core-storage

I converted a partition to a CoreStorage volume using this command:

```
sudo diskutil cs convert disk0s2 -passphrase test123
```

Now when I run `diskutil cs list' the output shows that I still only have a Logical Volume Group and a Physical Volume attached to it (from what I gather, I should have a Logical Volume Family and a Logical Volume as well). The status of the LVG is 'Offline' and the status of the PV is 'Checking'. It has been this way for over 10 hours on a 128GB SSD.

To me it seems this status indicates some kind of intermediary status, as if the conversion/encryption has not completed yet, is that assumption correct?

Is it safe to shut down the machine in this state?

---

In Disk Utility.app the disk name is shown in red! I can run the Verify Disk command and the output seems ok (ends with 'The volume {UUID of the LVG} appears to be OK' and 'The partition map appears to be OK').

But in the output of Verify Disk I see mention of a logical volume ('Logical Volume Group contains 1 Logical Volume'), which the output of `diskutil cs list` does not show. And following that, I see mention of two UUID's to which `diskutil cs info {UUID}` responds '{UUID} is not a CoreStorage UUID'.

To me this seems inconsistent, and I'd like to resolve this.

Edit:

I tried to manually create a Logical Volume (since it seems to be missing form the `diskutil cs list` output) using `diskutil cs createVolume {LVGUUID} jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%` which resulted in:

> Error: -69780: Unable to create a new CoreStorage Logical Volume

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after converting a disk. There was a message displayed by `diskutil cs convert`:

```
Couldn't unmount disk0s4; converted volume won't appear until it's unmounted
```

I solved the problem by unmounting the disk and repairing it :

```
diskutil unmount force disk0s4
diskutil repairVolume disk0s4
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue. Julien Eyriés - your answer worked well for me. I tip my hat.

Answer (score 0):

I attached my Time Machine drive to make a backup and then rebooted my computer. After reboot I was presented with the "Disk Password" by EFI ("test123" worked as expected) and then I had to log in to OS X with my account password.

`diskutil cs list` now shows the normal tree for a CoreStorage pool with one volume, and status is 'Online'. In System Preferences FileVault is encrypting with 18 minutes left. I am not sure if waiting another 18 minutes without rebooting would have updated the output of `diskutil cs list` or that my reboot triggered the updated output (and maybe the encryption as well).

TL;DR After converting it seems safe to reboot the machine.